# term_link filter rewrite link only applying half of condition?

Tags: filters

Can anyone clarify why this function is filtering all terms in the `highlight` taxonomy, but not filtering for the `subscribe-win` term?

Neither `$term->term_id` or `$term->slug` are working.

I don't get any errors and it is only filtering `highlight` - and not other taxonomies.

Thanks!

```
    add_filter( 'term_link', 'slick_term_to_page', 10, 3 );

    function slick_term_to_page( $url, $term, $taxonomy ) {

        if ( $taxonomy != 'highlight' && $term->term_id != 42 ) :
        // if ( $taxonomy != 'highlight' && $term->slug != 'subscribe-win' ) :  

            return $url;

        else :

            $url = home_url( '/win' ); 
            return $url;

        endif;
    }
```

Comment: The taxonomy of term 'subscribe-win' is 'highlight'?

Comment: `highlight` is the taxonomy. `subscribe-win` is a term in `highlight`. `42` is the `term_id`.... this filter should isolate the `42` but is not ... it's applying to every term in `highlight`.

Comment: Are you sure the term id of 'subscribe-win' is 42? Can you paste the var_dump of term object? Do you know the content of $url variable? What you want to achieve?

Comment: I think you dont need to specify the taxonomy, term id is unique for all terms of all taxonomies.

Comment: As followup, goal is anytime user clicks the `susbscribe-win` term they are taken to the `win` page - which is using a custom `page` template - and not an `archive` template ... Why, you ask? Because I want `page` features like comments and social sharing ... Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Lucas! I found this code as an example in several places ... still interesting that the `&&` doesn't work ... but this does :)

```
    add_filter( 'term_link', 'slick_term_to_page', 10, 3 );

    function slick_term_to_page( $url, $term, $taxonomy ) {

        if ( $term->term_id != 42 ) :
        // if ( $taxonomy != 'highlight' && $term->term_id != 42 ) :    
        // if ( $taxonomy != 'highlight' && $term->slug != 'subscribe-win' ) :  

            return $url;

        else :

            $url = home_url( '/win' ); 
            return $url;

        endif;
    }
```

Comment: Glad to help you! Thinking about this, if you deny that the taxonomy is 'highlight' you are denying the other terms of the taxonomy 'hightlight' should have the url '/win', not only the term that are only 42.

Comment: Still makes no sense ... with both conditions, all terms in `highlight` were getting the `win` URL ... I read it as "if not in highlight taxonomy and not term 42" ... Of course the single condition is fine by me, but the double conditions should have worked ... some things are meant to be mysteries :)